# traffic buttons not responding in MacOS application

Tags: macos, cocoa, nsview, nsbutton, first-responder

I am creating an application on MacOS and I am having this problem. I am using custom traffic buttons. When the window is not active if I click they do not respond, what I get is the window becoming active.
How could I fix that so the buttons will respond even if the window is not the active one.
I have them added to a custom view, here is what I have:
My View:

```
@implementation TrafficView

- (id)init {
  if ((self = [super init])) {
     trackingArea_.reset([[NSTrackingArea alloc]
      initWithRect:[self bounds]
         options:(NSTrackingMouseEnteredAndExited |
                  NSTrackingActiveAlways |
                  NSTrackingInVisibleRect)
           owner:self
        userInfo:nil]);
    [self addTrackingArea:trackingArea_.get()];
  }
  return self;
}

- (void)dealloc {
  [super dealloc];
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstResponder {
  return YES;
}

- (BOOL)acceptsFirstMouse:(NSEvent*)theEvent {
  return YES;
}

- (void)mouseEntered:(NSEvent*)event {
  mouseInside_ = YES;
  for (NSView* view in self.subviews)
    [view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (void)mouseExited:(NSEvent*)event {
  mouseInside_ = NO;
  for (NSView* view in self.subviews)
    [view setNeedsDisplay:YES];
}

- (BOOL)_mouseInGroup:(NSButton *)button {
  return mouseInside_;
}

@end
```

Now to add the buttons I do this in the window implementation (I will post the code for only one button)

```
trafficView_.reset([[TrafficView alloc] init]);
[self.frameView addSubview:trafficView_];


// close button is declared as NSButton
closeButton_ =
      [NSWindow standardWindowButton:NSWindowCloseButton
                        forStyleMask:NSTitledWindowMask];

[trafficView_ addSubview:closeButton_];
```

Note that my custom view (trafficView_) is added to the NSThemeFrame class, self.frameView

```
- (NSView*)frameView {
  return [[self contentView] superview];
}
```

I do not why the buttons do not respond. 
Could someone help on this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Just suggestions: what seems fishy is init instead of initWithFrame. I think [self bounds] will be 0,0,0,0. Also your implementation misses updatetrackingarea whenever the view size changes.  NSTrackingActiveAlways is correct. Just try to look what you did differently https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TrackingAreaObjects/TrackingAreaObjects.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000060i-CH8-SW1

Comment: If you add an `NSLog()` to your `acceptsFirstMouse:` method, is it getting called on that first click or not?

Comment: @MarekH I checked the update tracking area stuff, but I do not think this is the problem. I have added NSLog in mouseEntered method and whenever the mouse hover the traffic buttons I the log printed out. That means that my tracking area is working fine, doesn't it?

Comment: @bhaller: Adding the NSLog() does not print anything. I have added NSLog also in the sendEvent method of the window for mouseDown events and there I do see the log printed. The method is like this: `- (void)sendEvent:(NSEvent*)event {
    NSEventType type = [event type];
    if (type == NSLeftMouseDown)
      NSLog(@"sendEvent framed_browser_window::mouseDown");
    [super sendEvent:event];
  }` however in the mouseDown method of the view I see nothing. Any ideas please?

Comment: Just check InAppStoreWindow project how they do this. There might be something different to your implementation. I just know that apple started to fight against this customization (playing with nsthemeframe with superview/subview) since 10.10

Comment: @MarekH's suggestion sounds good.  I would add that if `sendEvent:` is called but `acceptsFirstMouse:` isn't, perhaps you can hack it by calling `mouseDown:event` directly on the clicked view from a `sendEvent:` override, to get around whatever Apple is doing that is getting in the way.  This would be a major hack, though, and I don't recommend it unless you can find no other fix.  Be very careful with it; call `super` from `sendEvent:` whenever you can, and do the hack only in the narrow case where it is needed.  I'm not posting this as an answer because it is too ugly and may not even work.

Comment: Finally I found the root of the problem. The view receiving the clicks was not TrafficView. I had another view added to window.frameView and apparently it was overlapping TrafficView. So the solution consisted of adding TrafficView after the other one.  Actually no need to implement `acceptsFirstMouse` since for buttons it returns YES by default